# Cant connect to Database. Visual Studio 2013 aspx

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2013, and SQL Server 2008 and 2012. They both support my computer. My database was created in VS2012 and i cant open it in VS2013. I installed all the tools that there is in VS2012. I tried to have a connection string in the Web.config. Everytime Im trying to send some data to my database, i get this message:

> The database 'C:\USERS\XXXX\DESKTOP\XXXXX\APP_DATA\DATABASE.MDF'
>   cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports
>   version 662 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported. Could not
>   open new database
>   'C:\USERS\XXXX\DESKTOP\XXXXX\APP_DATA\DATABASE.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE
>   is aborted. An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\XXXXX\app_data\DataBase.mdf failed. A database
>   with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it
>   is located on UNC share.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQMiE.png

What can I do next?
Thanks.

Comment: Wrap the code in a `try/catch` block and catch the `SqlException` that is being thrown.  It will give you the exact error.

Comment: Its to complicated to me, the code structure cant allow this...

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a database created for Sql Server 2012 with Sql Server 2008. To make this work, you need to open the database in Sql Server 2012 and change the compatability level from 110 (Sql Server 2012) to 100 (Sql Server 2008 and Sql Server 2008 R2). Hopefully you haven't used any features of Sql Server 2012 that will prevent this change.

Comment: Changing the compatibility level will still not make it possible to attach the database to a 2008 instance. Compatibility level is primarily about syntax and optimizer behaviors, not database versioning.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn
When Im trying to connect to my database to change to compatability level, this is the message that I get:http://i.imgur.com/KIVGJLn.png